# Not able to start Open Office from JOD converter

Tags: java, openoffice.org, jodconverter

I'm getting following exception while trying to connect to Open Office from JOD Converter:

javax.servlet.ServletException: org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.OfficeException: failed to start and connect
    org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:286)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)

I've already gone through [Jodconverter exception: failed to start and connect in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910548/jodconverter-exception-failed-to-start-and-connect-in-windows)
and followed the steps but I'm still getting same exception every time.
OO service is running on port 8100, I also tried by running it at 2002 but no luck.
Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue while using LibreOffice (= OpenOffice clone) and what worked for me was adding the following path to the PATH environment variable:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4.0\URE\bin
```

and reboot Windows!!

In your case it should probably be something like (not sure here, you have to check on your machine):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenOffice.org 3\URE\bin
```